# Mssql и Postgresql jdbc drivers внутри одного jar файла

Tags: java, sql-server, postgresql, gradle, jdbc

Мне в моем приложении надо уметь общаться и с `postgresql` и c `mssql`.
В начале приложение обращается k `postgre`, потом уже к `mssql`.

Пытаюсь сделать `fat jar` с помощью `gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.1.4'
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver',name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.4.0.jre8'
}

jar {
   manifest {
      'Main-class' : 'my.package.Main',
      'Class-Path' : '.'
   }

   from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

При попытке запуска jar файла пишет следующее :

```
java -jar myApp.jar

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:330)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:263)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:275)
```

Почитал в интернете, пишут что надо удалить сертификаты из jar файла.
Переписал таск jar таким образом :

```
from (configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
}
```

При запуске уже ошибка, что не может найтись драйвер для `postgre` :

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-database
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at my.package.Main.getConnection(Main.java:146)
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы у меня внутри `jar` были оба драйвера и я мог общаться и с `postgre` и c `mssql`?

Comment: а просто подключить два `jar``- а никак?

Comment: ну я щас тоже пришел к такому решению, через java -cp jar1:jar2:jar3 но хотелось бы как нибудь поудобнее

Comment: не вижу удобности в сливании разных jar.

Comment: @Tsyklop тут будет надо один jar тащить, а так еще надо будет дополнительно тащить отдельные jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, решением стало следующее ( :

1. Убрать зависимости от драйверов конфиге

   dependencies {

   }
2. Положить скаченные `jdbc` драйвера рядом
3. Запускать собранный `jar` с указанием `classpath'a` :

   `java -cp myApp.jar:postgresDriver.jar:mssqlDriver.jar my.app.Main`